# How to use response after POST Request?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to use data from response after `POST` request in Flutter/Dart?

this is my function:

```
  signIn(String email, pass) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    Map data = {
      'email': email,
      'password': pass
    };
    var jsonResponse = null;
    var response = await http.post("http://10.0.2.2:80/user/login", body: data);
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      if(jsonResponse != null) {
        print(jsonResponse);
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = true;
        });
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MainPage()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      }
    }
    else {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      print(response.body);
    }
  }
```

after run this function, my `jsonResponse` returns this data to me:

```
{id: 1, firstName: admin, lastName: admin, accountName: Kot filemon, email: admin@admin.pl, active: false, activateCode: 0, admin: true, latitude: xxx, longitude: xxx, profileImage: null}
```

so, how can I use this data(without another request to server) in my app on different screen?

I know how to use this type of data in react, because i'm a frontend developer but i don't have any idea how to use this here.

thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can save it to SharedPreferences  if all the data in this response are common for all screens.

Comment: I read that in sharedPreferences we should save only single data not all data from object

Comment: You can use this package https://pub.dev/packages/localstorage it is made for storing data like Json and getting data like Json

Comment: can you show me how to do this based on the code above?

Comment: See this example https://pub.dev/packages/localstorage#-example-tab-

Answer (score 0):

At this moment you cant store all that jsondata in one SharedPreferenceValue. You need to create one value foreach userdata like this:

```
signIn(String email, pass) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    Map data = {
      'email': email,
      'password': pass
    };
    var jsonResponse = null;
    var response = await http.post("http://10.0.2.2:80/user/login", body: data);
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      if(jsonResponse != null) {
        print(jsonResponse);
        // this lines save the user data in the sharedpreferenceinstance
        await prefs.setString('email',jsonResponse[email]);
        await prefs.setString('accountName', jsonResponse[accountName]);
        //-----------------now you cant send to another page
        // if you need to read the saved data use=>prefs.getInt('email');
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = true;
        });
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MainPage()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      }
    }
    else {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      print(response.body);
    }
  }
```